# Joomla 4: Counting New Zoo CCK Articles Since Last Visit Using Cookies in Custom PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla

I have seen a unique function on a news website homepage. Whenever a new article is publish in the backend, and the user is browsing the homepage, a button shows up that "X number of new articles are available" (the 'X' is the numeric showing the number of new articles) E.g.: 3 new articles are available. When I click on that button, the homepage is refreshed. I also want the same function on my Joomla website homepage. I am using Zoo CCK for creating articles.

**The HTML and CSS code is below:**

```css
.rf01{position:fixed;display:none;top:-195px;left:0;right:0;min-width:150px;max-width:200px;margin:auto;text-align:center;z-index:16;}.rf01.show{display:block;top:195px;}.rf02{position:relative;display:inline-block;min-width:150px;max-width:200px;height:32px;padding:4px 42px 4px 16px;background:#00aa5a;color:#fff;border:none;border-radius:16px;font:600 12px/1.0'Montserrat',sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;box-shadow:0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);transition:all .7s ease;}
.rf02:after{content:"";position:absolute;display:inline-block;top:0;right:0;width:22px;height:22px;background-position:-749px -141px;margin:5px 12px 5px 8px;}.rf03{font-style:normal;}
```

```html
<div id="refreshButton" class="rf01 show">
<button type="button" onclick="refreshPage()" class="rf02 spaf"><i id="newArticlesCount" class="rf03">0</i> New Article</button>
</div>
```

**The JS code is:**

```
<script>$(function(){function checkForNewArticles(){$.ajax({url:"/templates/bspk/refresh-count.php",type:"GET",success:function(response){$("#refreshButton").removeClass("show");if(response>0){$("#refreshButton").addClass("show");}$("#newArticlesCount").text(response);}});}setInterval(checkForNewArticles,5000);});function refreshPage(){location.reload(true);}</script>
```

**The code for refresh-count.php is below:**

```
<?php
// Load Joomla framework
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../'));
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Access Joomla application
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

// Load Zoo libraries
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_zoo/config.php';
$zoo = App::getInstance('zoo');

// Get last visited timestamp from cookie (or set default if not found)
$lastVisited = $app->input->cookie->get('lastVisited', time());

// Get current timestamp
$currentTime = time();

// Query for new Zoo items of type "article" published after last visited timestamp
$query = $zoo->table->item->getQuery();
$query->where('type = "article"')
     ->where('state = 1') // Published items
     ->where('publish_up <= ' . $currentTime)
     ->where('publish_up > ' . $lastVisited);
$newArticlesCount = $zoo->table->item->count($query);

// Update cookie with current timestamp
$app->input->cookie->set('lastVisited', $currentTime, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/'); // Expires in 30 days

// Echo the new articles count as response
echo $newArticlesCount;

// Exit to prevent further script execution
exit();
?>
```

Now the problem is with "/templates/bspk/refresh-count.php". I am using Joomla 4 and Zoo CCK for article creation. The **refresh-count.php**, in response, should show the number of new zoo items from the time the user (all types of users; not only logged in) has visited the page (based on saved cookies).

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

1. The CMS is Joomla 4
2. The PHP version is 8.2.4
3. The database prefix is "uzlei"
4. The database table structure for the Zoo item is "uzlei_zoo_item"
5. The Zoo Item Type is "article"
6. I want this function available for all types of users (not only for logged-in users, so use cookie instead of Joomla session)